# How to keep docker host machine up to date automatically?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-cloud

Say I have 10 docker host machines and I need to keep them up to date due to compliance reasons.

The (manual) steps would be:
1. Drain node
2. ssh into node
3. Perform update (and maybe reboot)
4. Undrain node

How do I get these steps to happen automatically? How do I coordinate so that only 1 machine is drained at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a job scheduler like [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/). It allows you to define *jobs* with several steps and advanced scheduling. Also allows you to easily monitor what happened during execution.